# post() method for passing a runnable to be run on the UIThread

Tags: android, view

at what circumstances, passing a runnable to the View class instance method post() would not work as expected, and will not Run the runnable - ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the activity is destroyed before the `Runnable` comes to the top of the queue, that might cause the `Runnable` to not run.

If the process is terminated, the `Runnable` simply no longer exists.

If you cancel the `Runnable`, it will not run.

If you are tying up the main application thread before the `Runnable` comes to the top of the queue, the `Runnable` will not run, and you will eventually crash with an ANR.

Comment: what do you mean tye up the main application?

Comment: @OfekRon: The main application thread is the thread you are on when you are called by Android with callback or lifecycle methods (e.g., `onCreate()`, `onClick()`, `onListItemClick()`). If you spend more than a couple of milliseconds in those methods, your UI will start to suck. If you *never return* from one of those methods, your UI will be frozen, and anything in the work queue (e.g., `post()`-ed `Runnable` objects) will be blocked from executing.

Comment: my problem is that I post a few runnables to update a text view, and the text and some of these posts gets executed some just not... it doesnt seem rational :\